# Can't play m4a files with Banshee

Tags: 11.04, banshee

I've installed the gstreamer set of codecs, logged out, reboot, but Banshee still doesn't play my m4a files.  Specifically, i installed

Gstreamer extra plugins
Gstreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime, musepack
Gstreamer plugins for aac, xvid, mpeg2, faad

Am i missing something else? a step or package?

- `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` is installed
- The movie plays fine in totem

It plays just fine on Totem! could it be because of the album artwork (which is showing as a "movie" and not being recognized by banshee?

Comment: Have you installed gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad? (`sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad`)

Comment: Can other gstreamer-based players play the files, such as Totem (Movie Player)?

Comment: @desgua - yes it's installed.

Comment: @MichaelMS - yes, it plays just fine on Totem! could it be because of the album artwork (which is showing as a "movie" and not being recognized by banshee?)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove or rename the local configuration in your home directory. See [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10/+bug/856988). The workaround works for me.

```
rm -r ~/.gstreamer-0.10
```

Comment: Seems to be some stale information. Deleting this does work. If you have presets you can be a bit more targeted and just run: `rm ~/.gstreamer-0.10/registry.*`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`? After installing that and restarting Banshee, you might be able to play your files.